# Not editable text in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Replaced text like this

```
QTextCursor cursor = mpEditor->textCursor();

cursor.beginEditBlock();

mpEditor->insertPlainText( inTxtReplace );

cursor.endEditBlock()
```

Visually everything is in order. But if you try to edit the text, it's nonsense, the characters are superimposed, you can not add anything. In what my mistakes?

Comment: could you be more specyfic, what you have and what you want? Also title sims unrelated to description.

Comment: QTextEdit contains text "h 1 h 2", I replaced "h" on "31" = "31 1 31 2" - visually it happened, but where I click on QTextEdit and entered text = nonsense, text overlaid another text and when and when I added the text at the end, it is not added.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you are not reading documentation.

See [QPlainTextEdit::readOnly](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#readOnly-prop).

Also if you using a text cursor use it modify document:

```
QTextCursor cursor = mpEditor->textCursor();
cursor.beginEditBlock();
cursor.select(QTextCursor::Document);
cursor.insertText(inTxtReplace);
cursor.endEditBlock()
```

Comment: It didn't help, the text is replaced, but I can't edit it. mpEditor->isReadOnly() = false